# VUEJS - Submit Form with EmailJS Error "The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form"

Tags: forms, vue.js, email, vuetify.js

I'm building my vue app where we can submit form, I'm using EmailJS and Vuetify, and I 've encountered some issue `The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form`. Here's the code:

**ContactForm.vue**

```
<v-form class="mx-8" ref="form" @submit.prevent="sendEmail">
        <v-col>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="from_name"
            name="from_name"
            label="Full Name"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="from_email"
            name="from_email"
            label="Email"
            required
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-col>
        <v-col>
          <v-textarea
            v-model="message"
            name="message"
            outlined
            label="Tell us about your ideas, the type of website you want, your target market, and your desired style."
            :rules="textareaRules"
          ></v-textarea>
        </v-col>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>

          <v-btn color="#99d215b9" class="card-button mb-4" type="submit">
            Submit
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-form>
```

**script**

```
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      from_name: "",
      from_email: "",
      message: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      emailjs
        .sendForm(
          "service_id",
          "template_id",
        {
         from_name: this.from_name,
         from_email: this.from_email,
          message: this.message,
         },
          "public_id"
        )
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS!", result.text);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("FAILED...", error.text);
          }
        );
    },
```

Does anyone know where my mistake is, to resolve this error `The 3rd parameter is expected to be the HTML form element or the style selector of form`?
I tried this parameter `this.$refs.form` [from emailjs doc](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/examples/vuejs/) but got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

hello i think you must edit your method like this

```
 methods: {
    sendEmail() {
      emailjs
        .send(
          "service_id",
          "template_id",
        {
         from_name: this.from_name,
         from_email: this.from_email,
          message: this.message,
         },
          "public_id"
        )
        .then(
          (result) => {
            console.log("SUCCESS!", result.text);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log("FAILED...", error.text);
          }
        );
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In the api documentation it says that it can be form selector (id) or HTMLFormElement through refs.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js">
</script>
<form ref="form" @submit.prevent="sendEmail">
<v-text-field label="Email" type="email" name="user_email" />
<v-text-field label="Name" type="text" name="user_name" />
<v-textarea label="Message" name="message" />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

```js
methods: {
        sendEmail()
        {
            emailjs.sendForm('YOUR_SERVICE_ID', 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID', this.$refs.form, 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY')
                .then((result) =>
                {
                    console.log("SUCCESS!", result.text);
                }, (error) =>
                {
                    console.log("FAILED...", error.text);
                });
        },
```

[enter link description here](https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/send-form/)